# I didn't received the message even after successful response in my WhatsApp template API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, postman, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I didn't received the message even after successful response in my WhatsApp template API,

Request:

```json
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "918291413565",
    "type": "text",
    "text": {
        "preview_url": false,
        "body": "Enter the Descrption"
    }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "input": "918291413565",
            "wa_id": "918291413565"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE4MjkxNDEzNTY1FQIAERgSN0NFRENCMjQ4N0VEOTYxRTI3AA=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check following things with provider.  1. Running status of the provider   2. Your credits. I have faced same issues too many times. And most of the times their servers were not running properly.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate which server should i check and the process to solve this problem

Comment: If you might don't know. Meta have recently introduced the Cloud APIs. So, previous and still there are many companies(Provider) which offers the WhatsApp messaging. You have to check with WhatsApp API provider company which you are using. It can be `meta` as well. As you are getting the proper response but not msgs. There is no issue from your end.

Answer (score 0):

[WhatsApp Business API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#sent-test-message), has a rule,

> Message templates are the only type of message that can be sent to customers who have yet to message you, or have not messaged you in the last 24 hours. Thus, message templates are primarily used to initiate conversations with customers.

It means the business can send other types of messages only if the user replies to the business in 24 hours window.

Second, WhatsApp will forward this kind of error in webhook only, so send message API response with success but to check the real state of the message you need to [set up webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks).